# Caliburn.Micro DataTrigger with RelativeSource TemplatedParent

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I developed an application with `WPF` without using a special `MVVM` framework. Now this application is getting bigger and bigger; therefore, I want to switch to `Caliburn.Micro`, but this causes somes problems.

I have a view containing `ListBoxes` inside an `ItemsControl`. In the `ListBoxItems` is a button placed, which has to change the opacity once the user hovers over the parent `ListBox` and once again, when the user hovers over the `Button` itself (and the way around, when the mouse leaves these controls again). To achieve this, I came up with this `xaml` code:

```
<Style x:Key="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOutStoryboard" />
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" x:Name="FadeInStoryboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseLeave">
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeInStoryboard" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeInStoryboard" />
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard}" x:Name="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsMouseOver, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOutStoryboard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PartiallyFadeInStoryboard}" x:Name="PartiallyFadeInStoryboard"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeInStoryboard" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeInStoryboard" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" x:Name="FadeOutStoryboard"/>
                 </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
```

Sadly, this is now, after I switched to Caliburn, not any more working, as the code of the last `DataTrigger` is not anymore executed. I think the reason for this behavior is that I previously used a `DataTemplate` inside the `ItemsControl` to define the view; but now I created an extra `.xaml` file/class just for the view of this items which are bound to the `ItemsControl` (which contains the `ListBox`) - therefore, the `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` might not be working anymore. Is this idea correct? How can I solve this issue in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a `{RelativeSource}` with an `AncestorType`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard" />
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeOutStoryboard" />
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PartiallyFadeInStoryboard}" x:Name="PartiallyFadeInStoryboard"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeInStoryboard" />
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeInStoryboard" />
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="PartiallyFadeOutStoryboard" />
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" x:Name="FadeOutStoryboard"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Change the latter to the type of whatever parent element you try to bind to.

Comment: This is working. But: I am using the same style for different buttons (once in the situation described above, and once in another `ItemsControl`), so that they do not always have a common ancestor type. Any idea about that?

Comment: That's another question. But if they don't have a common ancestor type, you will need to define two different triggers/different styles. You cannot dynamically change the binding of the data trigger somehow.